# Tag persion in page post/photo with Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I can programmatically post on behalf of a page. I want to be able to post **to** a person, or **tag** them in the post, or tag them in a **comment**. I just need anyway to create a post as a page, and have it tied to a user.

Edit: I just really want to be able to make a page post, and tag a user, or tag them in a comment, or tag them in a photo. Any form of tagging where they'd be notified.

I've tried tagging people in a photo. The tags appear as pending, there's no notification, and when I approve the tag, it vanishes permanently. So probaly not possible.

Here's my code so far:

```
        <?php

    $pageId = 'removed';
    // Pass session data over.


    // Include the required dependencies.
    require( __DIR__.'/facebook/autoload.php' );

    session_start();

    //$_SESSION["accessToken"] = null;

    // Initialize the Facebook PHP SDK v5.
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id'                => 'removed',
      'app_secret'            => 'removed',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    if(isset($_SESSION["accessToken"])){ //if authorized

        $photo = [
            'message' => 'Test message.',
            'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('glow.jpg'),
            'tags'    => array(
                 array(
                  'tag_uid'=> removed,
                  'tag_text' => 'name',
                  'x'      => '50',
                  'y'      => '50',
                 )
            )
        ];

        //auth page
        $response = $fb->get('/' . $pageId . '?fields=access_token', $_SESSION["accessToken"]);

        $pageNode = $response->getGraphNode();  
        $pageToken = $pageNode['access_token'];

        $response = $fb->post('/' . $pageId . '/photos', $photo, $pageToken);

        $postNode = $response->getGraphNode();  
        $postId = $postNode['id'];

        echo 'Page Token: ' . $pageToken . '<br />Post Id:' . $postId;

        $response = $fb->post('/' . $postId . '/comments', array (
            'message' => 'This is a test comment. @[{19292868552}:1:{Martin Firth}] tag thing.',
          ), $_SESSION["accessToken"]);

    } else { //not authorized yet
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        $_SESSION["accessToken"] = $accessToken;

        // Send the request to Graph
        try {
            $response = $fb->get('/' . $pageId . '?fields=access_token', $accessToken);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
            //echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

            $permissions = ['email', 'user_likes', 'publish_pages', 'publish_actions'];
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/terranova/site/', $permissions);
            echo ' <a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
          exit;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: i don´t think that´s possible. what for would you need that anyway? what´s the exact use case?

Comment: Users in store will request information, which the app will post to them via facebook. Could I post as the page, and then also post a comment as the Admin user, tagging the customer in the comment?

Comment: how do they request information? don´t they send a message to the page? you can reply to a message with the api.

Comment: The request information, in store using the app. The app will be authorised as the Page, to publish the requested info with the user tagged. Is this possible? I'm exploring uploading a photo and tagging them in the photo, which is working, but the tags are coming up as pending for some reason...

Comment: not sure if i understand, but user requests will get published on the page? what for? either way, i don´t think you can override the pending status, i actually hope it´s not possible. you should not tag users without their explicit permission.

Comment: I wanted something like:

Another photo selected by [@ user name]! 

And then the photo and some information posted, with the user tagged to find it.

Comment: you should edit your question to be a lot more detailed. include the code you have tried, and (very important in that case) include a screenshot how it looks like, and how it should look like.

Comment: Really? I figured it's straight forward. I want **any** way to tag a user in a page post. Either in the text, by photo, by comment, whatever. Tag a user in a page post.

Comment: i thought you did find out how it works already, only it is pending? you should include that code. also, i assume you would prefill the message parameter for it? because that would not be allowed according to the platform policy.

Comment: I've edited my post. Thank you for your help.